# MAP_READY not fired on Android

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm having trouble with an Ionic app ever since I moved the Google Map to another page. It was never on the root/home page. On iOS the map shows just fine, but on Android the MAP_READY event is never fired so in the sample below I do not see "Map is ready".

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        console.log('Platform ready');
        this.loadMap();
    });
}

loadMap() {

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
        camera: {
            target: {
                lat: this.lat,
                lng: this.lon
            },
            zoom: 5
        },
        controls: {
            myLocationButton: true,
            compass: true
        }
    };

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);

    console.log('Map created');

    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
        .then(() => {

            console.log('Map is ready!');
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Error is ",err);
            }
        );
)
```

Comment: does the promise catch an error?

Comment: I added .catch but that didn't get run either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be quite simple. The lat and lon values had not been set. On Android this meant the map was never declared ready, on iOS it showed the map at (0,0). All I needed to do was remove the camera attribute from `GoogleMapOptions` and set them when I had the real values

```
 let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
    controls: {
        myLocationButton: true,
        compass: true
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `HtmlElement` instead of `ID` .

```
  <div #maps id="maps">

  @ViewChild('maps') mapElement;
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create(this.mapElement.nativeElement);
  }
```

Comment: No change. I've added the error catching code to the example.

Comment: Did you check device console log?

Comment: Yes. On iOS it shows all three messages, "Platform ready", "Map created" and "Map is ready". On Android it only shows the first two.